# I'm trying to wrap my head around variable scoping in Node.js and Vows

Tags: javascript, node.js, bdd, vows

As an exercise in TDD in Node.js, I'm trying to implement a very simple "database" that stores things as flat files.  Here's the very beginning of the DB module code:

```
var fs = require( 'fs' );

exports.create = function( path, readycallback ) {
    new FlatFileDB( path, readycallback );
};

function FlatFileDB( path, readycallback ) {
    this.path = path;
    readycallback( null, this );
}

FlatFileDB.prototype.getPath = function() {
    return this.path;
};
```

The DB creation is asynchronous, and in my test case, I have a check to see if calling the create() function actually results in two distinct objects:

```
var vows = require('vows'),
    assert = require('assert'),
    fs = require( 'fs' ),
    flatfileDB = require( '../lib/flatfileDB' );

var twoDBs = {};

vows.describe( 'flatfileDB' ).addBatch( {
    'creating the database': {
        topic: flatfileDB,
        'calling create': {
            topic: function( flatfileDB ) {
                flatfileDB.create( './createTest', this.callback );
            },
            'results in an object with the path passed in': function( err, db ) {
                assert.equal( db.getPath(), './createTest' );
            }
        },
        'calling create more than once': {
            topic: function( flatfileDB ) {
                flatfileDB.create( './db1', function( err, newdb ) {
                    twoDBs.db1 = newdb;
                    flatfileDB.create( './db2', function( err, newdb ) {
                        twoDBs.db2 = newdb;
                        this.callback( null, twoDBs );
                    } );
                });
            },
            'results in two objects with different paths.': function( err, dbs ) {
                console.log( 'twoDBs.  db1: ' + twoDBs.db1 + ', db2: ' + twoDBs.db2 );
                console.log( 'dbs: ' + JSON.stringify( dbs ) );
                assert.notEqual( twoDBs.db1.getPath(), twoDBs.db2.getPath() );
            }
        }
    },
}).run();
```

The output of those two console.log lines surprises me, though:

```
twoDBs.  db1: [object Object], db2: [object Object]
dbs: {}
```

since I'm passing twoDBs to the test callback, I had expected dbs and twoDBs to be the some object, but they don't appear to be.  Can anyone help me out with what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dbs` scope is inside of that callback. You wont be able to access because invoke of `this.callback()` isn't scoped in that callback. You need to you pass it along with `this.callback(null, dbs, twoDBs)` or you create a var in `topic` and assign `dbs` to it in the callback. This isn't so much an issue with Vows; It has much more to do with JavaScript's lexical scoping and callbacks.

What I do in these cases is pass along needed vars by add parameters to `this.callback()`.

***Edit:** What's above isn't right, but the fix came out in the comments below:*

> If you put var that = this; in the topic and change it to
>   that.callback( null, twoDBs); what happens?

Comment: Thanks, but I think you're looking at the wrong log line - I've removed that first one and left in only the last two, which are the ones I care about.  I expect that this call:

`this.callback( null, twoDBs );`

will map to this one:

`'results in two objects with different paths.': function( err, dbs ) {`

which would result in `dbs` being the same thing as `twoDBs`.  But it isn't - and `dbs` isn't even undefined - it's an empty structure.

Comment: Quite right. I misread it. I'm not sure what the issue is, but something that concerns me is what `this` references in `this.callback( null, twoDBs );`.

Comment: That part concerns me as well, and I think it's a Vows-ism.  I've been working from the vows tutorial at http://vowsjs.org/, and NOT calling `this.callback( ... )` definitely results in my `'results in two objects with different paths.'` code not being called at all.

Comment: If you put `var that = this;` in the topic and change it to `that.callback( null, twoDBs);` what happens?

Comment: That clears it right up, thanks!  That.... Well, that hurts my long-time-Java-developer brain.

Comment: So, `this` in that callback is pointing to something that has a `callback()` function. The tests are moving along for some unknown reason. If you `console.log(this)` you will get an idea the context/scope that call back is being executed in.